# Try to delete data from two entities in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, delete-row

I try to delete record from two entities. Core data has two entities,with the names Student and Detail both have an inverse relationship. Relationship is

> Student -> Detail:detail Detail -> Student:student

Try to delete record from both entities from the table view. but when i try to delete, only entity Student from delete but from detail Entity can't delete. it shows me this error.

> -[NSSet isSubsetOfSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _mainContext = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];

        [_mainContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        Detail *detailEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        Student *studentEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSMutableSet *mySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        [mySet removeObject: detailEntity];
        [studentEntity removeDetail:mySet];
        studentEntity.detail = detailEntity;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_mainContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolve Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    } 
}
```

StudentCoredataclass.h

```
#import "Student+CoreDataClass.h"


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Student (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Student *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *study;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *number;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Detail *> *detail;

@end

@interface Student (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addDetailObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)removeDetailObject:(Detail *)value;
- (void)addDetail:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;
- (void)removeDetail:(NSSet<Detail *> *)values;

@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

DetailCoredataclass.h

```
#import "Detail+CoreDataClass.h"


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Detail (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Detail *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *contact;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *number;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) Student *student;

@end
```

FetchedResultController:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _mainContext = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO]]];

    //[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: @"detail"];
    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    [self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

    // Perform Fetch
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Comment: you are trying to remove an NSMutableSet, not an NSSet

Comment: but in my opinion you should do something like [studentEntity removeDetail:detailEntity]; instead

Comment: In which line replace your code [studentEntity removeDetail:detailEntity]; @ddb

Comment: add the source code of both strudent and detail coredata model and I'll tell you better in an answer ;)

Comment: Refer updated code @ddb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
        Student *studentEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [context deleteObject:studentEntity];
         NSError *error = nil;
        [context save:&error];
    } 
}
```

Next set the `Delete Rule` in the model to delete the detail when the student is deleted (and the reverse).  It is unclear to me why you have data split into two entities.

You should not remove the tableView's Cell here.  You should remove it when you get the delegate callback from the fetchedResultsController.  If you haven't implemented those methods, then you do so now.

Comment: Hey, but it only delete from Student entity can't delete from Detail entity. solve this problem.

Comment: Go to you model object (it ends .xcdatamodel - and shows your model visually).  Select the `Student` entity.  Next select the detail relationship.  On the right panel select the model inspector.  For `Delete Rule` select `Cascade`.  This means that whenever you delete a Student all of its details will also be deleted.

Comment: after give delete rule can't work show the same error: [NSSet isSubsetOfSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet

Comment: Did you replace your `tableView: commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath:` implementation with the one I posted?

Answer (score 0):

please, replace

```
[studentEntity removeDetail:mySet];
```

with

```
[studentEntity removeDetailObject:detailEntity];
```

Comment: show me error like this: Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "detail"; desired type = Detail; given type = Student; value = <Student: 0x6000000bb900> (entity: Student; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://B6333229-F4B1-42B8-A85F-5A5D14D1BFE8/Student/p5> ; data: {
    detail = "0xd000000000140002 <x-coredata://B6333229-F4B1-42B8-A85F-5A5D14D1BFE8/Detail/p5>";
    name = hnfgdfgf;
    number = 10;
    study = oioiyhuh;
}).'

Comment: other error like this: [NSSet isSubsetOfSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

Comment: are you sure detailEntity and studentEntity are bot binded and exist in core data?

Comment: yes, i also insert & retrieve in core data using relationship.

Comment: may I know why in your question source code are you deleting detailEntity from studentEntity and then adding it again to it? also there is another big issue in your source code, first you delete the return value of "[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]"

Comment: then you call it again and assign to detailEntity and then you call it again to assign to studentEntity... I don't know the meaning, but is not possibile that the statement "[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]" will return different results as many time you call it

Comment: please, share source code how are you managing self.fetchedResultsController